# No encuentra archivo para abrirlo usando la clase Desktop Java

Tags: java, java-8

Al ejecutar este código me falla alegando que el fichero indicado no existe.

```
try {
        File path = new File("HOLA.txt");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
    } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por incluir el código de tu pregunta. Por favor, procura incluir el mensaje de error completo (o un fragmento más extenso de la traza) para ver el error y no tu resumen ;) Y bueno... [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) no se refiere a tu escritorio de Windows (`C:/Users/usuario/Desktop`); es más bien una interfaz al manejador de ventanas para acceder a algunas funcionalidades básicas... dicho ésto, dónde está corriendo tu clase Java y dónde está el archivo?

Comment: El archivo lo sitúo en la misma dirección que mi clase java; el fallo es The file HOLA.txt doesnt exits.. dando IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Sugiero que le des la ruta absoluta, porque tú estás compilando la clase y está corriendo una instancia de la JVM con base folder en alguna parte, que puede no ser la carpeta donde está el archivo `.java`

Comment: FUNCIONA! Pero esto para trabajarlo de forma gráfica debe de dar fallo por lo que suelo trabajar más con la relativa...seria eso posible?? Y muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vale por lo comentado, llamando desde el src también funciona y a mi otra pregunta ya está resulta.

Comment: Pon tus hallazgos en una respuesta, que después puedes marcarla como aceptada :)